# 2010 Subaru Legacy weird bolt holding stereo

Tags: subaru, audio, legacy

I just tried to replace my 2010 Legacy's stereo today and found out that there is some weird bolts (refer to attached image) holding the stereo brackets. I can not get that bolt out.  Its got a head that I have never seen before. Can anybody tell me a tool to remove this?

**UPDATE:** Could not find any matching tool to take it out properly. Had to cut the bolt head with a rotary tool.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the damn thing out finally. Had to use a rotary tool to cut the head.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about this:

[image]

It appears to be a captured bolt ... you won't get the bolt itself out by itself. Look on the back side for a nut to take off, then the whole thing should come out. The hole just below it and the thing protruding through it appear to be an alignment nib.

Comment: aka captive nut

Comment: @Zaid - No, I'm the captive nut ... belong in the loony bin I tell yah :D

Comment: @Paulster2 - There is no nut on the back side. It's just the screw. Looks like I'm gonna have to cut this head to take it off.

Comment: @VajiraLasantha - Does it just screw into the polymer mount? Stereos usually aren't this hard to take out. Do you have a new bracket to put your new stereo into?

Comment: @Paulster2 - I think it has a captive nut similar to this.
http://uk.farnell.com/productimages/standard/en_GB/42251467.jpg

I need to use this same bracket to put new stereo in.

Comment: @VajiraLasantha - Two further suggestions: 1) Use a pair of vice grips to grab hold of it and turn it; 2) Glue something to the front of it so you can get a grip on it, such as another bolt or maybe even a nut. Whichever, replace the thing when you get it apart with something you can actually use.